# Is there a way to get responseText with async true using Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Hi I have a situation that I have to return responseText with async true.

```
var initAjax = function (){
  var customAjaxResponse = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            $(".preloader div").removeClass('hide');
        }
    }).done(function (jsondata) {
        $(".preloader div").addClass('hide');
        try {
            return jsondata;
        } catch (e) {
            generate("error", '<div class="activity-item"> \n\
            <i class="fa fa-ban text-warning"></i> <div class="activity">Sorry! we are unable to find requested data, kindly try after some times.</div></div>');
        }
    }).error(function (jqXHR, exception) {
        var error = "";
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            error = "No internet Connection found.";
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            error = "Page not found.";
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            error = "Internal server error occurred.";
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            error = "JSON Parse error occurred.";
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            error = "Your request has been timed out.";
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            error = "Ajax request has been aborted unexpectedly";
        } else {
            error = "Uncaught error occurred - " + jqXHR.responseText;
        }
        generate("error", '<div class="activity-item"> \n\
                <i class="fa fa-ban text-warning"></i> <div class="activity">' + msg + '</div></div>');
    });
   return customAjaxResponse.responseText;
}
```

Is it possible to return data with async:true because I can't show any ajax-loader image asyn:false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible. You can't return `responseText` from `async` call. Because `initAjax` will end it's exection, before `ajax` will get something from server.

A common way to get around of this is to return [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and wait when it will be resolved.

```
var initAjax = function (){
  var customAjaxResponse = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            $(".preloader div").removeClass('hide');
        }
    }).done(function (jsondata) {
        //done
    }).error(function (jqXHR, exception) {
        //error
    });
   return customAjaxResponse.promise();
}
var promised_data = initAjax();
promised_data.then( function( response ){
   //code to process response
} );
```

Also try to look to promise library's: Q, Bluebird ...

[Library's Comparison](http://complexitymaze.com/2014/03/03/javascript-promises-a-comparison-of-libraries/)

Another way to solve your issue is to use Babel's `async/await`. But, as far as I know, this syntax isn't part of es6 or es7.

Comment: Great, Works fine buddy.